# Parse XML and echo results

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm just learning PHP. I have a bunch of scripts I have started and one has me stuck. I'm fetching an xml and printing the results to the page. However I only want the rows where the refTypeID = 10 and also I need to trim the text "DESC:" out of the reason area.

My current code

```
<?php

// Populate the following with your API Data
$vCode = "XXXXXXX";
$keyID = "XXXXXXX";

// Create the URL to the EVE API
$eveAPI = "http://api.eve-online.com/corp/WalletJournal.xml.aspx?keyID=".$keyID."&vCode=".$vCode."";

// Get the xml data
$xml = simplexml_load_file($eveAPI);

// Loop Through Skills
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $value) {
   echo "Skill Number:".$value['refTypeID']." -- Skill Points: ".$value['ownerName1']." -- Level: ".$value['reason']."<br />";  
};

?>
```

What I'm parsing

```
<eveapi version="2">
 <currentTime>2012-11-12 10:36:35</currentTime>
  <result>
   <rowset name="entries" key="refID"  columns="date,refID,refTypeID,ownerName1,ownerID1,ownerName2,ownerID2,argName1,argID1,amount,balance,reason">
    <row date="2012-11-12 10:46:49" refID="6570815512" refTypeID="10" ownerName1="Captain Vampire" ownerID1="159434479" ownerName2="The Condemned and Convicted" ownerID2="98032142" argName1="" argID1="0" amount="5000000.00" balance="13072537.98" reason="DESC: something "/>
    <row date="2012-11-10 02:27:48" refID="6561124130" refTypeID="85" ownerName1="CONCORD" ownerID1="1000125" ownerName2="Justin Schereau" ownerID2="90541382" argName1="Unertek" argID1="30002413" amount="42300.00" balance="7972463.03" reason="10015:1,10019:1,11899:1,22822:1,"/>
    <row date="2012-11-09 23:27:24" refID="6560673105" refTypeID="85" ownerName1="CONCORD" ownerID1="1000125" ownerName2="Blackcamper" ownerID2="754457655" argName1="Illamur" argID1="30002396" amount="25000.00" balance="7930163.03" reason="11898:1,"/>
   </rowset>
  </result>
 <cachedUntil>2012-11-12 11:03:35</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Thank your for the answers. I tried Mohammad's first and it worked. What are the pros and cons between the 2 solutions suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xpath` directly as below

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($eveAPI);

/* Search for <a><b><c> */
$result = $xml->xpath('//result/rowset/row[@refTypeID=10]');

foreach($result as $value) {
  echo $value['reason'] = trim(str_replace('DESC:','',$value['reason']));
  echo "Skill Number:".$value['refTypeID']." -- Skill Points: ".$value['ownerName1']." -- Level: ".$value['reason']."<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked a treat. Also allowed me to add some math functions at the end with ease!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// Loop Through Skills
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $value) {
if($value['refTypeID'] == 10){
echo "Skill Number:".$value['refTypeID']." -- Skill Points: ".$value['ownerName1']." -- Level: ".str_replace('DESC:', '', $value['reason'])."<br />"; 
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to skip rows you don't need :

```
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $value) {
   if ($value['refTypeID'] != "10") {
      // skip
      continue;
   }
   //etc ...
}
```

and use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for remove the `DESC:` form your string:

```
$reason = str_replace('DESC: ','',$value['reason']);
```

NOTE: this also removes the space after `DESC:`